# Javascript window unload

Tags: javascript, onunload

I want to detecting if tab/window is close, if true will trigger to logout.php page. So I had this script.

```js
var unloaded = false;
$(window).on('beforeunload', unload);
$(window).on('unload', unload);  
function unload(){      
  if(!unloaded){
    $('body').css('cursor','wait');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      async: false,
      url: './logout.php',
      success:function(){ 
        unloaded = true; 
        $('body').css('cursor','default');
      },
      timeout: 5000
    });
  }
}
```

But somewhere in my script I also return get in URL

> `www.index.php?success` /  `www.index.php?wrongpassword`.

I used it to display a message if user update the table. So my problem here, it also will trigger to logout.php if user success update the table. Is there any condition to exclude get url like `www.index.php?success / www.index.php?wrongpassword` so it will not trigger to logout.php. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: use another variable like the way you use the `unloaded` variable

Comment: And if they reload the browser you are logging them out?

Comment: @epascarello I also had another script if they reload the browser it will logout as well. `console.info(window.performance.navigation); console.log(performance.navigation.type); if (performance.navigation.type == 1)  { window.location.pathname = "logout.php"; }`

Comment: This wouldn't be much use unless you have a single/one page website otherwise you will log the user out each time you navigate them or when they reload/refresh the page.